# Angularjs How To Redirect to UI State After Ajax Call

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, jsp

I am new to AngularJs, I need to redirect to new view after Progress page processed. I am using UI-Router in AngularJs for State navigation.

#### Progress.jsp

```html
<div class="myClass" ng-controller="payCtrl" ng-init="loadResponseData()" id="loadResponseData">
  <div class="row">
    // Progress Bar Section
  </div>
</div>
```

#### payCtrl.js

```js
$scope.loadResponseData = function() {
  $http.post(CONTEXT_PATH + getResponseData(function(data) {
    // Redirect to another JSP after process
    $state.go('response');
  });
};
```

#### Acknowledge.jsp

```html
<div class="myClass" ng-controller="payCtrl" id="acknowledge">
  <div class="row">
    // Response Section
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Main.jsp

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div data-ui-view=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### app.js

```
$stateProvider.state('response', {
        url : '/',
        templateUrl : CONTEXT_PATH+'getResponsePage'
);
```

#### Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getResponsePage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String backToQuote(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "/Acknowledge";
}
```

Is this correct approach to navigate.

Comment: if you are just changing views, then `$state.go(state)` (inject `$state` into controller)

Comment: Aleksey, Inside ajax state.go not working, please check my above update code.

Comment: does `$http.post` even resolve successfully? maybe you are not catching an error callback `$http.post(...).then(function(response) {...}, function(error) {...})`, which is what it returns from your backend

Comment: Aleksey.. Its coming into success block